# Как сделать генератор случайных чисел?

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы выпадали цифры от 1 до 5 с вероятностью:

1 = 70%,

2 = 20%,

3 = 5%,

4 = 4%,

5 = 1%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта задача решается очень просто.

```
function specialRandom() {
  var r = Math.random() * 100;
  if (r < 70) { return 1;}
  else if (r < 90) { return 2;}
  else if (r < 95) { return 3;}
  else if (r < 99) { return 4;}
  else { return 5;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/kaoq5yv0/3/

Как вариант.

Большую часть кода можно убрать, если вы сами будете следить, чтобы сумма интервалов была равна 100%.